# Why is self allowed in static context in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Why is using `self` allowed in static context in Objective-C?

I thought it was allowed and then I encountered memory errors that took me a week to find out that `self` is not an alias for calling other static methods from the class instead of typing the class name.

Xcode and its compiler seems very smart at finding common pitfalls, why isn't it even generating a warning about something like that?

Comment: "self" does generally represent the Class object when referenced within a class (+) method, so if I'm reading your question correctly I'd think it would have worked as you'd expected. Can you post some code that shows the confusion?

Comment: curiously I'd say it's not just allowed but actually preferred. If you refactor -> extract some +method code, the automatically created method invokes "self" rather than the class name.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

1. There is no such thing as a "static context" in Objective-C.  What we have instead are "class methods".  They definitely are *not* "static" methods.
2. Class methods (ones prefixed with a `+`) are *really* just instance methods on a particular `Class` object.  (did your mind just explode?)  And since you have a `self` variable accessible in an instance method, you naturally have a `self` variable accessible in the class method as well.
3. In a class method, `self` points to *the class itself*.
4. Just as you can do `[self performAction]` inside an instance method to invoke methods on this particular instance, you can do `[self performClassAction]` inside a class method to invoke methods on this particular class.
5. All `Class` objects are subclasses of `NSObject`.  So you can use any `NSObject` instance method on any `Class` object.  (did your mind just explode again?)

Comment: So why when instead of `self` I used the class name all my sigfaults had gone away?

Comment: about #5 - not quite. Instance methods belonging to *any* root class, not just NSObject, may be called as class methods. NSObject does make extensive use of this, but it's not limited to that class. Also, Class objects aren't subclasses of NSObject - the metaclass pointer for a Class struct points to the parent class' Class struct, and for a root class is NULL.

Comment: @Sherm Pendley: it is unclear what you mean when you say "the metaclass pointer for a Class struct...". If A's parent class is B, then A's metaclass's parent class is B's metaclass. Furthermore, the root class's metaclass's parent class is the root class itself. The question of what is the *class* of a metaclass object is a separate question altogether -- it is the metaclass of the root class.

Comment: I can see that its valid to call `[self classMethod]`, but its is considered good or bad practice?  For me it is a bit misleading since the use of `self` implies that it should be an instance method.

Comment: @Robert it's good practice to use `self` in class methods, because then it honors any subclassing that may have occurred.  It's the reason why `[NSMutableArray array]` returns an `NSMutableArray` and not an `NSArray`; it's essentially implemented as `return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];`

Answer (score 8):

`self` is only allowed within the context of an Objective-C method. By "static context" I assume you mean within a class method (that is, one whose signature starts with `+` rather than `-`.) Your assertion that "`self` is not an alias for calling other static methods" is incorrect.

`self` is allowed in those cases so that you can:

1. pass the class around as an object, since all Objective-C classes are themselves objects
2. send messages to a class without specifying the class name, in case a method is overridden in a subclass (`[Foo bar]` will use `Foo`'s implementation always; `[self bar]` will use whatever implementation is available in `self`.)

Answer (score 5):

It's allowed because `self` *does* refer to the class object when used in class methods. Is that what you mean by "static context?" If so, what memory errors were you having that suggested otherwise?