# "Invalid use of 'this' in non-member function" in objective-c context?

Tags: ios, objective-c, this, self

Using Xcode.

In this code (func is declared in interface), tells subj error, standing on string with 'self'.

```
+ (void) run: (Action) action after: (int) seconds 
{
    [self run:action after:seconds repeat:NO];
}
```

What the... ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self` is an **instance** variable used to refer to an instance of the current object.

You are attempting to use it in a **class level** method `+(void)...` where `self` has no meaning. Try using a shared instance, or passing an instance of the class in question to the method.

```
+ (void) run:(Action)action on:(MyClass*) instance after:(int) seconds
{ 
    [instance run:action after:seconds repeat:NO];
}
```

**EDIT**

My commenters have pointed out that `self` does have meaning in class level contexts, but it refers to the class itself. That would mean you were trying to call a method that looks like this:

```
 [MyClass run:action after:seconds repeat:NO];
```

Where you should be aiming for:

```
 [myClassInstance run:action after:seconds repeat:NO];
```

Comment: I believe self does have meaning in class methods.  It refers to the class the method is being called on.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325453/why-is-self-allowed-in-static-context-in-objective-c for details.

Comment: @James not quite! `self` in a class method stands for the Class object, and can indeed be used.

Comment: The question that Tom links to incorrectly refers to class methods as "static contexts" -- as the answers there point out, "static" is not a word that applies _at all_ to Objective-C class methods. You had the correct terminology in your first answer.

Comment: `self` is **not** an instance variable. It’s a hidden parameter that exists in every Objective-C method, be it an instance method or a class method.