# Class methods and self keyword in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Invalid use of 'this' in non-member function” in objective-c context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552037/invalid-use-of-this-in-non-member-function-in-objective-c-context)

If I use the keyword **self** inside a class method:

```
+ (id) myMetho
{
   self ...
}
```

Does it refer to the class or to the current instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it represents the class. For a longer answer, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552037/invalid-use-of-this-in-non-member-function-in-objective-c-context-wtf/7552069#7552069)

Answer (score 0):

self just means "the class you are in"