# super allocWithZone having some doubts in singleton class concept

Tags: objective-c

I am new in Objective-C and I am trying to create a singleton class based on [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32).

```
+ (MyGizmoClass*)sharedManager
{
    if (sharedGizmoManager == nil) {
        sharedGizmoManager = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return sharedGizmoManager;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [[self sharedManager] retain];
}
```

In this code `sharedManager` is a static method which will check if object of this class is present. If so it will return the previous created object, otherwise it create a new one.

I have some questions:

1. If `sharedManager` is static, how can it to access `super`?
2. When I print `[super class]` why does it give the current class name?
3. Why does `[[super allocWithZone:NULL] init]` is return the current class object?
4. If `super` is equal to `self` here than why its not calling current class's `allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone`?

Comment: You can have a look to [my previous post about singleton pattern implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912703/objective-c-static-field-and-implementing-singleton-pattern/6913036#6913036). If have put a lot of comments within the implementation code. Hope this helps

Comment: Why are you allocating super? Don't you want an instance of self instead?

Comment: That is an amazingly old document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers, though they point out good information with regard to singletons, didn't actually answer your question. Your question is actually mostly based on Object orientation, the fact that you specifically reference a singleton is incidental.

1. I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552069/916299) with reference to `self`, here is the paraphrased, important part of the answer

   > `super` does have meaning in class level contexts, but it refers to the superclass itself, not an instance
2. This one was throwing me off too. I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11827720/916299) and it was concluded:

   > `[super class]` calls the `super` method on the current instance (i.e. `self`). If self had an overridden version, then it would be called and it would look different. Since you don't override it, calling `[self class]` is the same as calling `[super class]`.
3. Are you sure it's actually returning an instance of this class? Or are you assigning it to an instance `sharedGizmoManager` of this class?
4. Super isn't equal to self, but some of the methods you have called: e.g. `[super class]` is calling the same implementation of the method that `[self class]` would call.

Comment: I think #2 misses the mark. super, a *keyword* which cannot be overridden, sends messages to the superclass. In a static +method (which are not true static methods but rather dynamic -methods of *Class* classes) the superclass is an *NSObject*. *NSObject*'s *class* method when invoked with `super` returns the subclass, so `[self class]==[super class]` in a static method.

Comment: NSObject's implementation looks like this:
`+(Class)class {
    return self;
}` --
`self` in this case, is the subclass, because that is where you're sending the message from. `+(Class)superclass` will have the desired effect, in which case you want `[self superclass];` (note +method).

Comment: @RiazRizvi, Feel free to amend answers!

Comment: OK I added an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a couple of things to consider here. First, the Cocoa Fundamentals guide is somewhat out-of date. It doesn't take into account some of the current technologies Apple has developed, like Grand Central Dispatch, and Automated Reference Counting. The [retain] in your allocWithZone method would not compile correctly in a ARC-enabled project (since you're new to Obj-C, I'm making an assumption here you're new to iOS/iPhone as well, and so you should read up on those two technologies).

There is a very good discussion of different singleton design patterns over in this thread:
[What should my Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like)

However that is an older thread, and as such does not take into account Automated Reference Counting (I've utilized Louis Gerbang's answer for years and it no longer works in ARC-enabled projects).

For ARC-enabled projects/files (yes ARC can be enabled just for single files) - we've moved to a singleton that uses GCD and works quite well:

```
static YourClassName * volatile sharedInstance = nil;

+ (YourClassName *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t sharedInstanceToken;
    dispatch_once(&sharedInstanceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[YourClassName alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

What's going on here? Well if you take a look through the [GCD docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html), you'll see dispatch_once only gets executed once during the entire lifetime of an application for a particular object. As the docs go onto say, this makes it very useful for creating singletons in a thread-safe manner.

On top of that, we declare the sharedInstance method as volatile, meaning the compiler/runtime should never try to cache a call to the method and should always execute the code inside. This makes sure we always call into GCD and that we always get back the object we're supposed to.

I'm glossing over a bunch since you're new to Obj-C, but definetly take a look into GCD, ARC, and then once you've got a solid grounding in Obj-C, looking into IMP caching, which is what volatile is preventing from happening.

Comment: great answer, I have recently switched to this way of creating singletons, but I had never heard about the word volatile!

Comment: Though you give good information about singletons, they question only incidentally references them. The question is actually about oop and which implementation of methods are called.

Comment: "we declare the sharedInstance method as volatile" - But you're declaring the static variable volatile, not the method. Volatile methods don't exist in Objective-C and method calls are never optimized away. Instead, you should move the static variable inside the method. That guarantees it is never accessed without calling the method.

Answer (score 3):

(1.) What is `super` in a 'static function'? In Objective-C, +methods are properly called *class methods*, -methods are called *instance methods*. These +methods are not true static methods because [Objective-C classes are themselves objects of an opaque type called *Class*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW18). So both `super` and `self` are defined in +methods. `super` sends messages to the superclass of *MyGizmoClass*, but when called from a +method `super` looks for an equivalent +method, and when called from an -method `super` looks for a corresponding -method.
`self` in +methods of *MyGizmoClass* returns *MyGizmoClass* which is a *Class*, whereas in -methods `self` is a pointer to a *MyGizmoClass* instance.

(2.) The method `+class` returns `self.isa`. Yes `[super class]` invokes the *superclass's:*`+class` method, however, when `self` is passed up to +methods neither its value nor its type are modified (whereas `self`'s type is cast to the superclass when it is passed up through -methods). So when an implementation of the `+class` method up the chain asks for `self.isa`, it gets the same value, *MyGizmoClass*. 
To be certain, you can verify that `super` does call `+class` in superclasses by deriving *MyGizmoClass* from a *MyGizmoSuperClass* where you can place an override:

```
    @interface MyGizmoSuperClass : NSObject
    @end
    @implementation MyGizmoSuperClass
    +(Class) class {
        NSLog(@"yes it calls MyGizmoSuperClass:class");
        return [super class];
    }
    @end
    @interface MyGizmoClass : MyGizmoSuperClass 
    +(Class) classviasuper;
    @end
    @implementation MyGizmoClass
    +(Class) classviasuper {
        return [super class]; //which version of class will super call?
    }
    @end
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
       NSLog(@"returned %@",[MyGizmoClass classviasuper]); 
    }
```

prints

> > yes it calls MyGizmoSuperClass:class
> >     returned MyGizmoClass

(3.) Again `super` calls the superclass version of `allocWithZone` but the `self` value passed to the method still points to a *MyGizmoClass*, and since `allocWithZone` returns an object of the receiver's class, you get a *MyGizmoClass* back.

(4.) You can easily verify `super` is different to `self`. If you implement `[self allocWithZone:NULL]` your code will call *MyGizmoClass*'s implementation of `allocWithZone` and loop indefinitely. With `[super allocWithZone:NULL]`, the superclass's version gets called.