# Why does "[self class] == [super class]"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, oop, superclass

I expected `[super class]` to return the superclass's class, however I found, using this code that it returns this class's class.

**Code**

```
NSLogObject([self class]);
NSLogObject([super class]);
NSLogObject([self superclass]);
NSLogBool([self class] == [super class]);
```

**Output**

```
[self class]: MainMenuScene
[super class]: MainMenuScene
[self superclass]: CCScene
[self class] == [super class]:[YES]
```

Can somebody explain why this happens please?. I expect it to return the same value as `[self superclass]`.

```
Macros:
-------
#define NSLogBool(i)   NSLog(@"%s:[%@]", #i, (i) ? @"YES" : @"NO")
#define NSLogObject(o) NSLog(@"%s:[%@]", #o, o)
```

Comment: And just incase I didn't say "class" enough: "Class class class class class!"

Comment: You shouldn't use apple prefixes in your own classes or macros (or just any other identifier)

Comment: I should if I want them to show up when I type NSLog... :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[super class]` calls the `super` method on the current instance (i.e. `self`). If self had an overridden version, then it would be called and it would look different. Since you don't override it, calling `[self class]` is the same as calling `[super class]`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just being dozy and assuming a method called "class" should somehow act differently to the rest of oop!

Comment: I admit I fell into the same trap for a second while reading your question. No worries.

Comment: even if you didn't override it, it is possible that `[self class]` is not the same as `[super class]`, if `self` is an instance of a subclass which overrides the method; then it would call that subclass's implementation

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. There is no `super` method. `super` is a keyword.

Comment: @RiazRizvi: What they meant was "the superclass's implementation of the method" without saying it in so many words.

Answer (score 3):

`super` refers to the method implementation in the superclass. If you don't override the method in your class, the implementation in your class and its superclass is the same.

Both `[super class]` and `[self class]` call the same method, defined on `NSObject`.

Comment: even if you didn't override it, it is possible that `[self class]` is not the same as `[super class]`, if `self` is an instance of a subclass which overrides the method; then it would call that subclass's implementation

Answer (score 0):

While the answers by mprivat and Sulthan are technically correct, the current case is a bit more complicated (and interesting):

Considering the implementation of the call to the method. It uses (of course) the object pointer. An object pointer is a pointer to a struct that has as its first element (`isa`) is a pointer to the objects class. The `class` methods (that is, as mprivat and Sulthan has stated correctly, the very same in both cases) follows this pointer to determine the class, i.e., always the **class of the calling object**.

As a result, if A is the superclass of B, both calls `[self class]` and `[super class]` called by an instance of B, return the class of B (**not** of A, what one may expect because of a missing override!).