# returning an integer from a method in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am having a problem figuring out how to simply return an integer from a method.

Here is what I have:

simple.h

```
@interface simple : NSObject {
}
- (int)simpleMethod;
@end
```

simple.m

```
#import "simple.h"
@implementation simple
- (int)simpleMethod {
    return 0;
}
@end
```

simpleViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)simpleButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    int test = [simple simpleMethod];
}
```

I am getting a warning on the line "int test..." that says, "simple may not respond to '+simpleMethod'". And another warning that says, "Initialization makes integer from pointer without cast".

My program is crashing on this line, so although this is just a warning it seems to be a problem.

I want to be able to use "simpleMethod" without creating an instance of the class "simple". Is this possible?

Problem fixed: changed the - to a + as per Peter's suggestion.

Comment: does `simple.h` define `queryDatabase`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently you have simpleMethod defined as an instance method.  But to do what you want to do, you need to define the method as a class method:

```
@interface simple : NSObject {
}
+ (int)simpleMethod;
@end

#import "simple.h"
@implementation simple
+ (int)simpleMethod {
    return 0;
}
@end

- (IBAction)simpleButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    int test = [simple simpleMethod];
}
```

Note the "+" on the method definition

Also the typo(?) where you had the class definition of `queryDatabase`, but the class implementation of `simple`

Comment: It seems like a typo in OP's post, but `queryDatabase` should really be `simple`.

Comment: @Anurag  Yeah I just saw that too

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use NSInteger. They are the same thing, but I believe it's more correct formatting wise(since I see you are interacting with a UIViewController).

Also it's important to note that you will not be able to access instance methods with self in class methods, because obviously there is no instance for self to point to. As Josh pointed out below you can use self, but it points to the class, not an instance of it.

+ symbol is a class method

- is an instance method.

```
@interface Simple : NSObject 
+ (NSInteger)simpleMethod;
@end

#import "Simple.h"
@implementation Simple

+ (NSInteger)simpleMethod 
{
   return 0;
}
@end

- (IBAction)simpleButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
   NSInteger test = [simple simpleMethod];
}
```

Comment: `self` is indeed defined in class methods; it points to the class object, which is an instance of the metaclass. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6325469/ What you can't access in class methods is _instance variables_.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. My intention was to tell him that you can't call instance methods from class methods. I personally use the class name instead of self so as not to create any confusion as to what I'm accessing.

Comment: Be careful with that; any method that could be used by a subclass should use `self`.

Comment: Another good point, thanks Josh. Didn't even think about potential subclassing issues with that.