# What is the expected behaviour using self in Objective-C class functions?

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking through some code in production at work which I did not write but looking it over it uses a pattern I don't regularly see which is to use `self` inside of a class method.  The basic format is...

```
+(void)myClassMethod
{
  if (self.myClassStaticProperty > 0)
  {
    ... do stuff ...
  }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what `self` returns in this case but the code does seem to work and given the structure it's returning an instance of the class it's contained but I don't understand how.  What is the expected behaviour using self inside of a class function?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325453/why-is-self-allowed-in-static-context-in-objective-c

Comment: Amazing.  Thanks @CoachNono.